# Generics, abstract classes, constructors

Tags: c#, generics, collections, constructor

I have an abstract base class

```
class AbstractClass 
{
    Col<AbstractClass> parent

    public AbstractClass()
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

I have two implementations

```
class A : AbstractClass 
{ 
    Col<A> parent

    public A(Col<A> parent)
        :base(parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }  

}

class B : AbstractClass 
{ 
    Col<B> parent

    public B(Col<B> parent)
        :base(parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

I have a collection

```
class Col<T> : IList<T> where T : AbstractClass
```

Which is to be used in another class as `Col<A> and Col<B>`, let's call this class `C`.

```
class C
{
    List<A> a = new List<A>()
    List<B> b = new List<B>()
}
```

This would all work, except that I want types `A` and `B` to know about their parent collection. I thought having the following constructors in `AbstractClass`, A, B would be ok, but it seems generic constraints are only available for classes and not on methods. Essentially I would like the following constructors:

```
public AbstractClass(Col<T> where T : AbstractClass)
public A(Col<A>)
public B(Col<B>)
```

instances of A, B need to know what collection they're in, but I can't call the base constructor from the derived classes because they're different types.

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand it, this can't be done in C# **2.0**. The functionality is already sitting in the CLR, but C# doesn't allow it. In C# 2.0 we have invariant generics. In C# 4.0 there will be support for variance.

Here are my references:

http://blogs.msdn.com/rmbyers/archive/2005/02/16/375079.aspx

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfuture

http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL16/

Am I right?

Answer (score 4):

I often use a pattern related to the C++ [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) when I want to do something like this:

```
abstract class AbstractClass<TDerivedClass>
    where TDerivedClass : AbstractClass<TDerivedClass>
{
    Col<TDerivedClass> parent;

    public AbstractClass(Col<TDerivedClass> parent)
    {
        // do stuff
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}

class A : AbstractClass<A>
{ 
    public A(Col<A> parent)
        :base(parent) {}
}

class B : AbstractClass<B>
{ 
    public A(Col<B> parent)
        :base(parent) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want types A and B to know about their parent collection

You might be interested in [this article](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/06/12/c-parentchild-relationship-and-xml-serialization/). I wrote it with XML serialization in mind, but it can be used in a more general context

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom `Collection<T>` type instead of a `List<T>`. They basically provide the same functionality (`Collection<T>` uses `List<T>` internally), and is intended precisely for this purposes.

You can then override `InsertItem` to set the parent of any item added to the collection.

```
public class MyCollection<T> : System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>
{
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
        item.Parent = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: so, do away with the constructors?

Comment: @Matt: I didn't include the constructors the purpose of conciseness. You'll want to add in the constructors that chain to the base ones though, of course.

Comment: I've edited my question to better explain my problem. I think we're on the right track here though

Comment: No, this won't work. I'd stil need something like protected Col<AbstractClass> parent in the Abstract class, to be overidden by protected Col<A> parent in A, and protected Col<B> parent in B.

Comment: @Matt: You could hide the `Col<AbstractClass>` property in the base class using the `new` keyword, or just leave it how it is and cast it. You can't override however, and this is something you'll have to live with.

Comment: Also, note that you can have generic type constraints on methods/constructors. e.g. `public void Foo<T>(T bar) where T : AbstractClass { ... }`

Comment: @Noldorin: Thanks. You're right: the problem is currently unsolveable with generics in c# 2 :)